# How can I get the GeoVisibleRegion of a space-based camera sensor given it's altitude, lat, long, and pointing view vector with respect to nadir?

Tags: geodesy

GeoVisibleRegion by itself provides the largest view attainable based on the curvature of the earth from a given altitude above the surface. How do I set up the problem for a narrower field of view for a camera sensor in space? I am interested in both a circular and rectangular field-of-view. Any bootstrapping of the problem would be so deeply appreciated. Another variant of the problem also includes what is the earth view (no-mapped regions).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.